# Maven deploy to JBoss very slow on Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: java, maven, jboss

We are using Wildfly Maven plugin v1.0.1. Final to deploy a couple of different Java 7 (1.7.0_79) projects to Wildfly 8.1.0. Final running on the local machine. We follow this process on Linux machines, OS X and Windows 7 Enterprise PCs with the exact same projects and even the exact same copy of Wildfly running. The specs of all the machines are fairly on par.

On the Linux and OS X machines all deploy within a few seconds. The Windows machine however hangs at the deploy stage for almost 2 minutes.

I do know if the Windows Firewall is active, but unfortunately our corporate policies prevent me from turning it off or even viewing the logs, so I'm not sure if it is the case.

I have also played with the system proxy settings to see if maybe it is trying to go out first, but to no effect.

What could be slowing the deploy on the Windows 7 Enterprise machine?

Comment: what is the version (professional, ultimate, home) of Windows 7 and what is the (exact) version of your jre/jdk ?

Comment: @MarceloBezerra, added versions Java 1.7.0_79 and Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: more questions: can you show us the pom.xml of at least one of the applications being deployed to this jboss? whats is the size of the war/ear files being deployed? what is the configuration of the hardware (RAM size, processor, hard drive size and speed)? this windows is running on a real or on a virtual machine? what are the jvm configurations (xmx, xms, min and max permgen/heap size....) applied to this jboss?

Comment: there are many possible reasons for slow builds involving maven, but they are not specific to Windows or any OS... take a look here : http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-site-build-is-very-slow-dependency-report/ and here: https://whatiscomingtomyhead.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/if-your-maven-site-build-is-too-slow/